# How do I check if a string matches a certain type of string format that I created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a string matches a certain string format by using lists like this:

```
# Creating the lists

year = ["%02d" % x for x in range(2015, 2100)]
month = ["%02d" % x for x in range(13)]
day = ["%02d" % x for x in range(32)]

# Checking if the string is in a certain format

if "2017-7-16" == f"{year}-{month}-{day}":
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

But that doesn't seem to be the way to do it, is it even possible?

Comment: please paste the complete code.

Comment: Sorry I clicked post accidentally lol

Comment: @Pythonieer, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer which helped you most or at least comment why you can't apply any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [`date.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) to convert string to [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) object and then check if date is after 2015.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import date

fn = "2016-10-28"
assert 2015 <= date.fromisoformat(fn).year <= 2100
```

**Upd.**

If your filenames is not in ISO format (not zero-padded month) you can split string, convert each item to int and pass into a [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) constructor:

```
assert 2015 <= date(*map(int, fn.split("-"))).year <= 2100
```

**Upd. #2**

Also you can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

fn = "2016-10-28"
assert 2015 <= datetime.strptime(fn, "%Y-%m-%d").year <= 2100
```

Comment: I know the `AssertionError` is intentional, but do you know that `ValueError` will also be raised in some cases?

Comment: @AnnZen, it's just test code, not full solution, so let it be

Comment: Okay, but `date.fromisoformat` in new in 3.7.  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS, released in Feb 2020, and it has 3.6.

Comment: @alaniwi, you can use other two options.

Comment: Both of the other two options (and possibly the first, I wouldn't know) will accept `'2020-6-21'`. Now if the intention is to *accept* single-digit months or days (for valid dates), then great. But the question is vague and *possibly* the intention is to test whether the date conforms to yyyy-mm-dd format, in which case it needs stricter parsing. I think that clarification from the OP is required.

Comment: @AnnZen Expanding on your wonderful `AssertionError` observation, all of the tests would be wrong since OP's list generator produces year values only up to 2099.  According to this set of assertions, `"2100-01-01"` would incorrectly pass.

Comment: @MarkMoretto, delete one symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a `date` object and then compare to bounds also in `date` objects. This has the benefit that things like wrong day count for the month are caught.

```
import datetime

def in_bounds(datestr, mindate=datetime.date(2015, 1, 1),
        maxdate=datetime.date(2100,12,31)):
    print('try', datestr)
    try:
        mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
        print('got', mydate)
        if not mindate <= mydate <= maxdate:
            print('out of bounds')
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        print("fail")
    else:
        print("pass")

test = ["2015-2-11",     # good
        "2015-1-01",     # good
        "2100-12-31",    # good
        "2014-12-31",    # low
        "2101-1-1",      # high
        "2020-9-31",     # 30 days in september
        "2020-13-2",     # bad month
        "These are the times", # not a date
]

for datestr in test:
    in_bounds(datestr)
```

Comment: Interesting, in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) said: `%m` -  Month as a **zero-padded** decimal number, but in fact it works without. Sorry, they also mentioned next: *When used with the `strptime()` method, the leading zero is optional for formats `%d`, `%m`, `%H`, `%I`, `%M`, `%S`, `%J`, `%U`, `%W`, and `%V`. Format `%y` does require a leading zero.*

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Yes, and the documentation is annoying that way. It uses the same codes for parsing and printing. `strftime` pads with zeros, but `strptime` does not require them. I noticed I didn't check bounds correctly. I've added a few more tests.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that they document that. I just cursed the darkness.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple solution:**

```
year = ["%02d" % x for x in range(2015, 2100)]
month = ["%02d" % x for x in range(13)]
day = ["%02d" % x for x in range(32)]

if any("2017-7-16" == f"{y}-{m}-{d}" for y in year for m in month for d in day):
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

**Output:**

```
b
```

Comment: Rather inefficient solution to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regular expressions!

```
import re


# Our date-format pattern
# The curved brackets indicate how many to match.

dt_pattern = r"""
    \d{4}  # Look for four numbers
    -      # Look for a dash
    \d{2}- # Look for two numbers
    -      # Look for a dash
    \d{2}  # Look for two
    """
# That pattern looks like this when not verbose:
#    r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"

# Compile with re.X flag to handle verbose pattern layout from above.
p = re.compile(dt_pattern, flags = re.X)
```

Test incorrect format

```
if p.match("2017-7-16" ):
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Output:

```
b
```

Test correct format

```
if p.match("2017-07-16" ):
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Output:

```
a
```

Comment: What about `"2017-2-30"`?

Comment: Won't be correct since `2`  needs to be padded, per OP's list.  Otherwise, you could use `r"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}"` to account for zero-padded days and months.

Comment: It's not padded in example provided in OP, but even if it will be, it's not correct date.

Comment: @OlvinRoght question is so vague that I don't know if it is required to accept this format (apart from the wrong number of days in Feb) or to complain that it is not yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: The output of OP's test case should be 'b', indicating that there isn't a match.  Formatting like `"%02d"` means two spots with zero padding if the numeric value is a single digit.  Did you try out OP's code?  It looks like you're just hopping around criticizing everyone in hopes that your solution gets selected.

Comment: @alaniwi For sure, when it comes to checking date formats, there are a lot to consider and using something from the standard library is probably the best idea.

Comment: @MarkMoretto, keep calm, I'm just pointing possible mistakes.